# Send text using bash mail which email client will see and display as text?

Tags: bash, email, text

Email sent using bash email displays terribly in the receiving email client cause it is displaying it using its default non-monotype font.

I've broken it down to a simple example.

Looked a little at uuencoding and making it an attachment but decided there must be some simple way to say ~"here comes some text" or wrap it in html which I can do but how to then push html into the the mail command.

A csv file:

```
$ cat file.csv
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER-3
value,value,value
value,value,value
$
```

A prettier view of the csv file:

```
$ column -ts, file.csv
HEADER1  HEADER2  HEADER-3
value    value    value
value    value    value
$
```

This is exactly as I want to display in the email somehow telling it to use monotype font.

I want to do this:

```
$ column -ts, file.csv | mail -s "subject" user@someplace.com
```

Expected (excuse the bkgrd colors):
[Nicely lined up text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJb25.png)

What I get:
[same text badly formatted in email client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKpgm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do exactly what you are attempting to with the command line mailer [S-nail](https://www.sdaoden.eu/code.html) which is the most recent fork of [Heirloom mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html) which are all derivatives of Berkley mail. The command is `mailx` for all packages, and will take input piped to `stdin`. The package is a full featured command line mailer with a wide range of features and attachment support.

For your case, you could simply do:

```
$ column -ts, file.csv | mailx -s "Subject Line" recipient@somedomain.com
```

with bash you can also use *process substitution* and avoid the pipe:

```
$ mailx -s "Subject Line" recipient@somedomain.com < <(column -ts, file.csv)
```

Or if you simply wanted to include the file as an attachment, you could do:

```
$ echo "attached" | mailx -s "Subject Line" -a file.csv recipient@somedomain.com
```

Check your distribution as it probably provides either `s-nail` or a `mailx` package for installation.

**Example Resulting E-mail**

Snippet from full-header included to show formatting and encoding.

```
To: david@nirvana.xxxxxxxxxxx.com
Subject: csv column
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-Id: <20190511072931.BB7AF122BED@wizard.xxxxxxxxxxx.com>
From: david@wizard.xxxxxxxxxxx.com (David C Rankin)

HEADER1  HEADER2  HEADER-3
value    value    value
value    value    value
$
```

Comment: I started using mailx originally.  I should have mentioned it.  I just tried this and nothing changes and it displays poorly in Outlook which leads me to believe it is the configuration of Outlook messing up the display and that that what I've been sending has been fine all along.

Comment: Oh.... God Yes, Outlook is using a proportional-font instead of a fixed-width font. Microsoft thinks mail should contain html and a whole lot of other nonsense. You can force Outlook to display in a fixed-width font, but that would be on a per-computer basis, or you could wrap your content in some type of html that Outlook understands -- but that I can't help with `:)`

Comment: So, I tweaked Outlook "stationary" to use a monotype font and it displays more like expected.  All my previous test cases also. I guess I should create an HTML message with a text section as I'd tinkered with a little while debugging the problem I didn't really have on the send side.

Comment: Our comments passed with the same realization.  Thanks.  Problem solved :-)

Comment: Yes, and I can recall long ago actually have this issue where I ended up creating an html <table> from the data and sent that so the columns would be aligned regardless of the font. So that is another option to the stationary. Good luck with the task.